# How to restore .sql file to ms sql 2008 , i m not having .bak file

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2

How to restore `.sql` file to `Sql server 2008` , I do not have `.bak` file.
I tried to search every where but can't find solution.

Pls Help if anyone knows.

Comment: What's in the _.sql_ file? statements to create the db?

Comment: script contain scheme and data both

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you dont have the `.bak` file then either create it else there is  **no** way to restore your database(including .sql file).

You need to have the .bak file to restore your database(including .sql file) else it is not possible.

**EDIT:**

As commented by OP, the solution that helped to him is:

```
C:\Users\Administrator>sqlcmd -S . -E -i C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\scr.sql
```

Comment: find out something like that, sqlcmd -S myServer\instanceName -i C:\myScript.sql , but facing  network related error

Comment: I got it, Kindly note it will be helpfull to all        C:\Users\Administrator>sqlcmd -S . -E -i C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\scr.sql"

Comment: @Anurag:- Updated that in my answer so that it may help others in future!

Comment: @Anurag:- You can accept the answer(A right tick mark which turn green when clicked) so that it may help others facing the same issue in future.

Answer (score 1):

`.sql` files are typically run using `Sql Management Studio`. They are basically saved SQL statements, so could be anything. You dont "import" them, more precisely, you "execute" them. Even though the script may indeed insert data.

To restore you may need backup ie. `.bak`

Comment: sqlcmd -S myServer\instanceName -i C:\myScript.sql but network related error occured.

Comment: check sql services are on